# Why does the sticky element not stick to the top when the flex element is full-width?

Tags: css, flexbox, sticky

I have a flex div that contains two further elements. When viewed fullscreen on a desktop, one of the elements acts as a sidebar. On smaller screens, the elements collapse to be displayed one on top of the other.

This technique is explained on [Every Layout](https://every-layout.dev/layouts/sidebar/).

I want to introduce a sticky element that will be used for navigation. On a wide screen, it works as expected. I can scroll the page and the sitcky element sticks to the top. However, in a narrower window, the element does not stick. It scrolls out of view – the same in both Safari and Firefox.

```css
  .with-sidebar {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .with-sidebar > :first-child {
    flex-basis: 20rem;
    flex-grow: 1;

    background-color: green;
  }

  .with-sidebar > :last-child {
    flex-grow: 999;
    min-inline-size: 50%;

    background-color: red;
  }

  .sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top: 1rem;
  }
```

```html
<div class="with-sidebar">
  <div>
    <h1>Sidebar</h1>
      <div style="height:10rem">Spacer</div>
    <div class="sticky">
      <h1>Sticky Element</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Not Sidebar</h1>
    <div style="height:200rem">Spacer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Among other things, I have tried wrapping the sticky inside another element, tried applying `align-self: flex-start;` to the sticky. I haven't yet found anything that works.

How can I ensure that the element is sticky when the sidebar and not-sidebar are stacked vertically as well as when they are alongside each other?

**Update**

I have experimented with placing `.with-sidebar` within a taller wrapper. Now it is clear what is happening. The element which is not the sidebar is pushing the sticky element off screen. This never happens when the elements are side by side. But, in a smaller window, the not-sidebar element is directly beneath the sticky element.

```html
   <div style="height: 400rem">
      <div class="with-sidebar">
        <div>
          <h1>Sidebar</h1>
            <div style="height:10rem">Spacer</div>
            <div class="sticky">
              <h1>Sticky Element</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Not Sidebar</h1>
          <div style="height:60rem">Spacer</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to redo the markup (or design). See, for example, if you specify a height for a block, in which the "sticky element" is located, `div:has(.sticky) { height: 500px; }` then the element starts to "stick a little", or another example, change nesting

```html
<body>
  <div class="with-sidebar">
    <div>
      <h1>Sidebar</h1>
      <div style="height: 10rem">Spacer</div>
      <!-- <div class="sticky">
            <h1>Sticky Element</h1>
        </div> -->
    </div>
    <div class="sticky">
      <h1>Sticky Element</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>Not Sidebar</h1>
      <div style="height: 200rem">Spacer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

and add a property *align-self* for this element.

```css
.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top: 1rem;
    align-self: flex-start;
}
```

But I don't think that's all for you. This is just an examples so you can see how the element works. The specification [CSS Positioned Layout Module Level 3](https://CSS%20Positioned%20Layout%20Module%20Level%203) very briefly describes the behavior of elements when positioned sticky.

Answer (score -1):

Use media queries for top position if 10rem is not as you want...

```css
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10rem;
}
```

Update: I clarify my thoughts:

```html
    <div class="with-sidebar">
        <div>
        <h1>Sidebar</h1>
            <div style="height:10rem">Spacer</div>
            <div class="sticky_desktop">
                <h1>Sticky Element</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="sticky_mobile">
                <h1>Sticky Element</h1>
            </div>
            <h1>Not Sidebar</h1>
            <div style="height:200rem">Spacer</div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

```css
.with-sidebar {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.with-sidebar > :first-child {
    flex-basis: 20rem;
    flex-grow: 1;

    background-color: green;
}

.with-sidebar > :last-child {
    flex-grow: 999;
    min-inline-size: 50%;

    background-color: red;
}

.sticky_desktop {
    position: sticky;
    top: 1rem;
}

.sticky_mobile {
    position: sticky;
    top: 1rem;
    color: violet;
}

.sticky_mobile>h1{
    margin-block-start: 0;
    margin-block-end: 0;
}


@media screen and (min-width : 656px ){

    .sticky_mobile {
        display:none;
    }
}

 @media screen and (max-width : 655px ){

    .sticky_desktop {
        display:none;
    }
 }
```